# Java Image Processing: Why is the output image smaller in storage than the input image?

Tags: java, image

I'm learning Java Image Processing. Here is my code:

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class LoadImage {
public static void main(String[] args) {    
    int width = 1280;
    int height = 720;

    BufferedImage image  = null;

    // READ IMAGE
    try {
        File input_image = new File("E:\\SELF-TAUGHT LEARNING\\39. Image Processing with Java\\test-image.jpg");
        image = new BufferedImage (width,height,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);
        image = ImageIO.read(input_image);
        System.out.println("Read successfully");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: " + e);
    }

    // WRITE IMAGE
    try {
        File output_image = new File("E:\\SELF-TAUGHT LEARNING\\39. Image Processing with Java\\test-image-output.jpg");
        ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", output_image);
        System.out.println("Writing successfully");
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("Error: "+ e);
    }
}
}
```

So the input image is around 300kb. But the output image is only 48kb. Why? Thank you

Comment: WHY THE SHOUTING IN THE TITLE?

Comment: Did you check whether the written image uses the same level of JPEG compression as the original image?

Answer (score 0):

If the image is the same resolution and quality after saving the new version, it's likely just a difference of metadata and formatting. It's also possible, however, that you are getting a lower quality image - if the original image had a high enough quality setting, it may not be noticeable when Java saves it at a lower quality.

Some things to check:

- do the before and after images look different?
- is the after image smaller in size?

I'm not very knowledgeable about Java, and don't know a lot about their image processing, but I would imagine there are methods for setting image size, resolution, and quality. I do, however, work with images a lot, and I know there are a lot of optimizations (especially in JPEG images) that you can do to reduce file size without affecting visual quality noticeably.